# Acessar servidor sem IP público

Tags: ip

Eu possuo um servidor linux em casa e gostaria de acessar os serviços dele(SSH, HTTP, GIT) remotamente porém eu não possuo um IP público. Há maneiras de fazer isso?

Comment: IP público me refiro a um ip externo, digamos assim, onde eu posso acessar o mesmo e ver meu servidor, porém o meu ip público/externo é do meu provedor, eu acesso o IP pelo browser e abre o servidor do meu provedor.

Comment: Realmente essa pergunta nao tem muito a ver com o assunto site mesmo. Agora, é provedor a rádio? Fazia tempo que eu nao via isso, provedor que não dá IP válido pra cliente.

Comment: Sim, é internet via rádio porém dedicada.

Comment: Devido ser internet via rádio, eu tinha pensado em fazer uma VPN e tentar um port forwarding, porém não sei se é possível.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic/550#550 Aparentemente esse é um assunto não muito popular entre o que deve fazer parte do nosso escopo. Todos com reputação mínima podem participar lá na escolha dos tópicos que devemos permitir aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Samuel, você pode utilizar um dos serviços gratuitos de DNS existentes como o www.noip.com, com ele você cria um domínio, como por exemplo: samuel.no-ip.info

O NoIp oferece um app, que você instala no seu servidor, que fica responsável por atualizar seu ip dinâmico e te permitir acessar seu servidor sempre pelo domínio que você criou (samuel.no-ip.info).

---

Vi nos comentários da pergunta que sua conexão é via Rádio... durante um período utilizei esse tipo de conexão em casa e também recebia o IP do provedor :(

Se sua experiência for parecida com a minha, meu roteador, responsável pela conexão com o provedor, tinha um IP fixo dentro da faixa de IP interna do provedor... se você conseguir que seu provedor direcione uma porta aleatória, tipo 4213 por exemplo, para o IP do seu roteador, você criaria uma regra no seu roteador para direcionar as conexões que chegassem nesta porta para o IP do seu servidor.

Se isso for possível você conseguiria acessar seu servidor colocando o IP do provedor e a porta direcionada (ipDoProvedor:4213).

Comment: Sim, já tentei com o no-ip, porém ele pega o ip do provedor e abre a página do mesmo.

Comment: Qual o seu provedor? Atualmente utilizo o no-ip sobre conexões do Oi Velox e também da GVT e tem funcionado bem pra mim. Vi que você mencionou que seu servidor é linux, também já trabalhei com linux/no-ip/velox (na realidade utilizei o serviço, não montei o servidor) e funcionava corretamente.

Comment: [SantiagoNet](http://santiagonet.com.br/)

Answer (score 0):

```
> Ctrl+R = Executar 
Executar > cmd > ipconfig > Gatway IP O Ip que tiver no Gatway copie e cole no Navegador, algum aparecerá o Do modem / roteador que pedirá login.
```

Comment: O servidor é linux, porém com o IP do gateway eu sou redirecionado para meu provedor de internet

Answer (score 0):

Samuel já tentou pegar seu IP [através de qualquer site](http://meuip.datahouse.com.br/) que forneça seu IP externo e tentar acessar remotamente?

Se não tiver nenhuma configuração de firewall que possa bloquear a conexão, acredito que é para funcionar.